# Remove whitespaces in pyspark dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe whose the schema is as follows:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to remove the first whitespace (if exists) in each element of the array in the value column
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
I think it will be like the code below:

```
df.select(regexp_replace(col("values"), \s*, *)).show()
```

The df:

```
+---+------------------------+
|key|                   value|
+---+------------------------+
| k1|       [  x1 x2, x3, x4]|
| k2|      [x5,   x6 x7,  x8]|
| k3|[ x9 x10, x11,  x12 x13]|
+---+------------------------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---+------------------------+
|key|                   value|
+---+------------------------+
| k1|         [x1 x2, x3, x4]|
| k2|         [x5, x6 x7, x8]|
| k3|  [x9 x10, x11, x12 x13]|
+---+------------------------+
```

(All the whitespaces before the arrays' elements must be eliminated)
Thank you

Comment: could you add sample input data  and expected output just to make question more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`posexplode`** to update `first space` if exists.

```
df.show()
#+---+----------------+
#|key|           value|
#+---+----------------+
#|  1| [a b, b c, c d]|
#|  2|[z x, xu, l z u]|
#+---+----------------+
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.selectExpr("key","posexplode(value)").withColumn("col",when(col("pos") ==0,regexp_replace(col('col'),' ','').otherwise(col("col")))).show()
#+---+---------------+
#|key|          value|
#+---+---------------+
#|  1| [ab, b c, c d]|
#|  2|[zx, xu, l z u]|
#+---+---------------+
```

For **replacing whitespace at start** case you can use

**`Spark-2.4+:`**

```
#+---+-----------------------+
#|key|value                  |
#+---+-----------------------+
#|1  |[   a b i,    b c, c d]|
#|2  |[   z x u, xu, l z u]  |
#+---+-----------------------+
df.selectExpr("transform(value, x -> regexp_replace(x,'^\\\s+','')) as dd").show(10,False)
#+------------------+
#|dd                |
#+------------------+
#|[a b i, b c, c d] |
#|[z x u, xu, l z u]|
#+------------------+
```

**`For Spark <2.4:`**

```
df.selectExpr("key","explode(value)").withColumn("value",regexp_replace(col("col"),"^\\s+",'')).groupBy(col("key")).agg(collect_list(col("value"))).show()
#+---+-------------------+
#|key|collect_list(value)|
#+---+-------------------+
#|  1|  [a b i, b c, c d]|
#|  2| [z x u, xu, l z u]|
#+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want it works only for the beginning of each element. I put an example of the expected result

Answer (score 3):

For removing spaces only at the start of the string. Use `ltrim`

```
    # Input DF
    df.show(truncate=False)

    +---+------------------------+
    |key|value                   |
    +---+------------------------+
    |1  |[  x1 x2, x3, x4 ]      |
    |2  |[x5,    x6 x7, x8]      |
    |2  |[ x9 x10, x11,  x12 x13]|
    +---+------------------------+

 df.withColumn("value", F.expr('''transform(value, x-> ltrim(x))''')).show(truncate=False)

    +---+----------------------+
    |key|value                 |
    +---+----------------------+
    |1  |[x1 x2, x3, x4 ]      |
    |2  |[x5, x6 x7, x8]       |
    |2  |[x9 x10, x11, x12 x13]|
    +---+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want it works only for the beginning of each element. I put an example of the expected result

Comment: @Sadek, you can use `ltrim` to remove any space at the beginning of each element.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's the same as proposed by @Shu and it works nice

Comment: > It's the same as proposed by @Shu

Except for the use of `F.expr` and not `F.selectExpr`. `F.expr` is probably what most users with this question are actually looking for.